# Iphone get free space

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this method to get the device free space(found it in web):

```
-(float)getFreeSpace{  
float freeSpace = 0.0f;  
NSError *error = nil;  
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:kSongsFolder error: &error];  

if (dictionary) {  
    NSNumber *fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemFreeSize];  
    NSLog(@"%d",fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes);
    freeSpace = [fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes floatValue];  
} else { 
    //Handle error
}  
return freeSpace/1024;
```

}

now i get from this method 8687616.0 and when i check in the device properties i have a 8.1 GB free.

how can i get the free space in MB? and did this method good,because there is a different between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes/(1024 * 1024) gives you size in MB
```

Answer (score 0):

the size is in KB, you will have to devide it once more by 1024. and if you need it in GB then again devide by 1024